# PHP get facebook posts

Tags: php, facebook

```
$data  = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/246179452202174/posts?access_token=TOKEN");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

print_r(array_values($data));
```

That's my code. It's simple. I can see the data and when I visit the link, it gives me the same info. So that works perfect. Underneath there's some outputs from the api.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 246179452202174_685970631556385 [from] => Array ( [name] => LGB eSports [category] => Sports Team [id] => 246179452202174 ) [message] => We are back! Sorry that we have been silent! But the silence is over! We will soon update you with some breaking news, stay tuned! Do not move your eyes! You do not want to miss this... [privacy] => Array ( [value] => [description] => [friends] => [allow] => [deny] => ) [type] => status [status_type] => mobile_status_update [created_time] => 2016-05-26T13:12:23+0000 [updated_time] => 2016-05-26T13:12:23+0000 [is_hidden] => [is_expired] => [likes] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1042109789201130 [name] => Fabio Broggi ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 713442998796859 [name] => Christian Bråten ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1801480580073327 [name] => Paulo Henrique ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 971217726332439 [name] => Benjamin Holm Davidsen ) ) [paging] => Array ( [cursors] => Array ( [before] => MTA0MjEwOTc4OTIwMTEzMAZDZD [after] => OTcxMjE3NzI2MzMyNDM5 ) ) ) )
```

When I try to echo `$data` or maybe `$data[1]` or something like it, it wont work. Also removing `array_values` gives me a output of "Array" or "ArrayArray".

So how may I print out the data from the api? It wont work, also; how may I fetch the image? I'd like to print the title of the post, and the image. As a link for a feed at my site.

More response code for link:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 246179452202174_685970631556385 [from] => Array ( [name] => LGB eSports [category] => Sports Team [id] => 246179452202174 ) [message] => We are back! Sorry that we have been silent! But the silence is over! We will soon update you with some breaking news, stay tuned! Do not move your eyes! You do not want to miss this... [privacy] => Array ( [value] => [description] => [friends] => [allow] => [deny] => ) [type] => status [status_type] => mobile_status_update [created_time] => 2016-05-26T13:12:23+0000 [updated_time] => 2016-05-26T13:12:23+0000 [is_hidden] => [is_expired] => [likes] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1042109789201130 [name] => Fabio Broggi ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 713442998796859 [name] => Christian Bråten ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1801480580073327 [name] => Paulo Henrique ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 971217726332439 [name] => Benjamin Holm Davidsen ) ) [paging] => Array ( [cursors] => Array ( [before] => MTA0MjEwOTc4OTIwMTEzMAZDZD [after] => OTcxMjE3NzI2MzMyNDM5 ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 246179452202174_680011585485623 [from] => Array ( [name] => Yoyo xno [category] => Musician/Band [id] => 281466768681242 ) [to] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => LGB eSports [category] => Sports Team [id] => 246179452202174 ) ) ) [message] => GG - Spotify: https://open.spotify.com/track/7tT6XVWfjtpNF8enpFpZT4 [privacy] => Array ( [value] => [description] => [friends] => [allow] => [deny] => ) [type] => status [status_type] => wall_post [created_time] => 2016-05-12T17:33:49+0000 [updated_time] => 2016-05-12T17:33:49+0000 [is_hidden] => [is_expired] => [likes] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 196458690716329 [name] => Funny memes pics ) ) [paging] => Array ( [cursors] => Array ( [before] => MTk2NDU4NjkwNzE2MzI5 [after] => MTk2NDU4NjkwNzE2MzI5 ) ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 246179452202174_676411742512274 [from] => Array ( [name] => LGB eSports [category] => Sports Team [id] => 246179452202174 ) [message] => Breaking news! Changes in the team. We are sad to announce that Aurora will part ways with Lgb Female. We wish to thank her for the time she spent with us and we wish her all the best for the future. Here's what she says about this herself: "My time with LGB eSports has come to an end. I am extremely thankful for the opportunity to grow within this team, go to amazing places and meet amazing people. I have learnt so much from this experience and I will never forget all the adventures we've had together! I would like to use this moment of change to look back and sincerely thank all my team-mates for this learning experience, Per Lilliefelth for looking after us, our sponsor Intel for taking care of us and LGB eSports for their immense contribution to helping us grow as an all-female team in Counter-Strike. I am certain I will still remain close to the team and look forward to seeing them at many future events. As for myself I am currently a free agent and look forward to continuing my journey as a competitive CS:GO player for many more years to come. Regards, Aurora Lyngdal" [picture] => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/13174168_676411742512274_4595019159434717947_n.jpg?oh=dad6bffaf94a2eae60c578d58f7cf8fc&oe=57E7E3F3 [link] => https://www.facebook.com/LGBeSports/photos/a.252900201530099.1073741829.246179452202174/676411742512274/?type=3 [name] => Timeline Photos [icon] => https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/photo.gif [privacy] => Array ( [value] => [description] => [friends] => [allow] => [deny] => ) [type] => photo [status_type] => added_photos [object_id] => 676411742512274 [created_time] => 2016-05-04T15:08:52+0000 [updated_time] => 2016-05-11T20:30:20+0000 [shares] => Array ( [count] => 4 ) [is_hidden] => [is_expired] => [likes] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1756499731303402 [name] => Antony Giordans ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 196458690716329 [name] => Funny memes pics ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 10205058377778051 [name] => Charmaine Anne D. Better ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 992479757539742 [name] => Yunus Emre Çeker ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 244636029237859 [name] => Roman Hardinger ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 1134092109982746 [name] => Khoa Nguyen ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 525969817592366 [name] => Joseph Turton ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 1152533898100318 [name] => Kristian Sørensen ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 1193252910715325 [name] => Kamil Grochu Groszek ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 1158759100821275 [name] => Ace Kjirkovski ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 10153477966360064 [name]
```

Answer (score 0):

you must echo this variable

```
$data[0][0]['message']
```

Comment: $data[0][0]['message']

Comment: please execute this code and give me output print_r(($data));

Comment: $data[0][0]['message']

Comment: @hakimRasfi , output in question ^

Comment: $data[0][0]['message'] gives out blank too

Comment: give me output please [delete (array_values)]print_r($data)

Comment: @hakimRasfi it's the same: Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 246179452202174_685970631556385 [from] => Array ( [name] => LGB eSports [category] => Sports Team [id] => 246179452202174 ) [message] => We are back! Sorry that we have been silent! But the silence is over! We will soon update you with some breaking news, stay tuned! Do not move your eyes! You do not want to miss this... [privacy] => Array ( [value] => [description] => [friends] => [allow] => [deny] => ) [type] => status [status_type] => mobile_status_update [created_time] => 2016-05-26T13:12:23+0000 [updated_time] =>

Comment: echo $data['data'][0]['message']

Comment: its not the same value printed there are difference between print_r($table) and print_r(array_value($table))

Comment: Omg, you must be an angel. Please do an answer to this, with image and link if possible. And I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 246179452202174_685970631556385 [from] => Array ( [name] => LGB 
-----------------

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 246179452202174_685970631556385 [from] => Array ( [name] => LGB eSports [category] => Sports Team [id] => 246179452202174 ) 
---------------
you show Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] in the first output ?
in the second Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] 
just little difference bro

Comment: Please answer the question so I can mark as correct answer

Comment: echo $data['data'][0]['message']

Comment: Yes that part you helped me with, but I'd like to get the link too

Comment: hi i dont have facebook .. then i cant help you more ..you can give me another response code with image nd link nd i can help you